# String substring

Tags: java, android, строки

имеется строка last, которая получает текст с поля, к примеру 124, нужно при нажатии кнопки удалить последний символ, в слушателе кнопки прописал данный код, в NetBeans все работает(выводит строку 12), а в AndroidStudio не работает(выводит строку 124)

```
String last = textView_sum.getText().toString();
            last.substring(0, last.length() - 1);
            textView_sum.setText(last.toString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

обманываете, наверно=)

```
String last = textView_sum.getText().toString();
last = last.substring(0, last.length() - 1);
textView_sum.setText(last);
```

Так попробуйте

Comment: я не понял, в чем разница но это помогло))))

Comment: Вы не присвоили строке новое значение, тоесть её подстроку

Comment: спасибо вам))))))